# Programatically pause and restart spouts in a topology

Tags: apache-storm

I have this case where i need to programatically stop  spouts and restart them with newer parameters on change from an external event. Think of this as an external system giving me an expiring key access to a message source.

So once i hit the expiry , i need to renew this token and re-initiate the spout. I have been trying with storm-signals (https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-signals/) to accomplish this. Although i can get the message into the spout , restarting the spout seems to be not working. The other options are to restart the topology as a whole (Nimbus API?) , and i dont want to do that. 
Any pointers appreciated

Comment: Why doesn't the spout just renew the token when it expires as part of the nextTuple call? Does the renewal have to be triggered by an external program?

Comment: Also what do you mean when you say you want to restart the spout?

Comment: Checking this for every iteration of the nextTuple seemed an overhead. This was more like a token that resets every 24 hours and unfortunately there is  no API on the source pipe to check if the connection is still "alive" of sorts. Hence had this thought of a seperate thread "signaling" the spout. I meant spout restart because if the flow was through the open->nextTuple route i could reconnect as well!. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a couple of shots at giving an answer to this, because your situation is still a little unclear to me.

**Solution 1: The spout updates the token**

If your spout has an expiring token that it uses to connect to your data source (e.g. a JWT), and it needs to renew it periodically, the ideal solution would be that you put an expiration timestamp on the token, so the spout can request a new one when the old token is close to expiration, or have the spout request a new one when the data source returns an unauthorized error. Checking a timestamp should be only a minimal overhead, so you should be able to do it on every nextTuple call.

**Solution 2: External process uses storm-signals and the Nimbus API**

If the spout for some reason can't renew the token itself, or you don't want to do the renewal in nextTuple, you could consider using https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-signals/ (as you linked) along with the Nimbus API, and have an external process update the credentials.

If you make the spout reconnect in the `activate` method instead of the `open` method, you could use storm-signals to send the credentials to the spout. Once the spout has received the credentials (you could use https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-signals/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/contrib/signals/StandaloneSignalConnection.java to receive a signal back from the spout when it has updated the credentials), you can use the Nimbus API to cycle activation for the topology. Storm will call `deactivate` followed by `activate` on the spout, which should let you reconnect.

**Solution 3: External process uses only storm-signals**

There is nothing preventing you from having the spout cycle the connection when it receives a signal with updated credentials, without you having to touch the Nimbus API. Just have the `onSignal` method set a flag in the spout when you receive new credentials (I believe onSignal runs in a separate thread from the rest of the spout methods, so keep in mind you should use AtomicBoolean/Reference for this), which you check in `nextTuple`. When `nextTuple` sees that the flag is true, you set it to false and cycle the connection/reinitialize the spout.

My preference would be solution 1, if possible. Having an external process update the credentials adds complexity, and means you have to deal with e.g. the token getting updated too rarely, or the external process being down, as well as how to handle the signaling between the spout and external process.